# avoiding unique key collisions across tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.5, data-warehouse

This might be related to the idea of data warehousing, but i'm not sure, though it is extreme theory.

We have a table where records get written to first, let's call it `tbl_recording` which looks like:

`CREATE TABLE tbl_recording (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  registration VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  legacyid VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX legacyid_UNIQUE (legacyid ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (id));`

Then, we have yearly tables based off of `tbl_recording` so like `tbl_recording_2012`, `tbl_recording_2013` etc etc,  their structure is the same.

We also have `tbl_recording` data off to the yearly table every hour (insert to yearly, delete from recording).  Now, the problem I see is that the uniqueness of `legacyid` is not remembered across all these tables. So, while we generate a hash for the legacyid, there could be a collision (even though terribly unlikely) at some point:

1. After data is removed from `tbl_recording` the same hash could be generated and re-entered into `tbl_recording`, thus causing a blockage further down the line when trying to insert into the yearly table
2. <s>Between years, the same hash could be generated for 2013 and 2014</s> **EDIT:** This would never happen if i append the year to the hash

The best way I've come up with to mitigate against this is to keep a hashtable,  one that stores all hashes created, and is checked against before a record is inserted, and then that fresh hash inserted into the hashtable.

Are there better solutions to this or is that the only real solution?

edit:  I've created an SQL Fiddle of an example of how my system works

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/231fa/1

pretend that: `tbl_data_2012` will never be written to again.  `tbl_recording` is constantly being written to but every hour or so, it's the contents it's being emptied to `tbl_data_2013`.  `tbl_recording` has already dumped it's contents to `tbl_data_2013` so when the 4th record was written there was nothing in there previously, thus it has created a new `legacyid`, however that `legacyid` already exists in `tbl_data_2013`

Comment: Why do you hash `legacyid` instead of just keeping it?

Comment: what do you mean?  `legacyid` is just a varchar which will be a hash.

Comment: deleted mine answer... first place some create table statements and some example data on SQLfiddle so we know want you are talking about..  and you will never avoid unique key collisions across tables partitioning is the only logical approch for this..

Comment: see recent edit @RaymondNijland

Comment: @Jarede what is it a hash of?

Comment: @Matthew well it's just a straight MD5 hash which admittedly gives it a 1/2^128 chance of a collision, but if there is a collision, it's knowing how best to mitigate it that helps.

Comment: if it understand it correctly tbl_recording->(4,'Jeff', 'AQ', now(), "2013BDRBBCCC12AAA"); should give an error?? because 2013BDRBBCCC12AAA already exists within tbl_data_2013-> ('Jill', 'AC', '2013-11-13 08:01:51', "2013BDRBBCCC12AAA");   how do you generate that legacyid?

Comment: Yep that's correct.  Tough one isn't it?  The `legacyid` is generated via a server side hash function.

Comment: @Jarede lost the scope off this question saw it again because njkroes posted an answer... well table tbl_recording is later on updated to the correct table? so record (4,'Jeff', 'AQ', now(), "2013BDRBBCCC12AAA"); will be inserted into table tbl_recording_2013 and the hash part 2013 gives an hint because this hash could be an duplicate within the tbl_recording_2013 table...

Comment: @Jarede still think that table partitioning (like mine first anwser) is still the best option because you can partition on year and you should create an unique index on legacyid so mysql will throw an 1062 error what means an duplication. i think you don't (your point 1) want the stall (wait) times because an duplicated legacyid could be generated and the application needs the generate an new one.. if this is the case then yes an precalculated hashtable (lookup table) is your very best option only problem is that you need extra selects, updates and dont forget diskspace to store data and index

Answer (score 3):

**You should separate the table on year to get faster insert's, updates or deletes because we expect lots lots lots lots lots lots off records in this table..**

**But... your problem is precisely the reason why separating tables on meta data (year in your question) is an SQL anti pattern, you could not have giving us an better use case*

If you want an better solution you should read about mysql partitioning see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html

Comment: with the removal of my second concern by appending the year, partitioning would still not help with the first concern, surely?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the ins and outs of MySQL as I'm a SQL Server guy myself, but what's the reasoning for splitting out your data into yearly tables?

I'm thinking doing something with table partitioning where you partition on the year. This would give you the ability to keep all the data together in one logical table and enforce uniqueness as well and give you the ability to spread out the physical locations of each partition.

This would also simplify things like reporting.

Comment: undelete mine answer and because ive also had mentioned table partitioning..

Comment: Somehow I missed that. My bad.

Comment: Well it's not your bad.. i did "delete (marks it invisible for all users expect for me)" that answer and "undelete" what is possible here..

Comment: I'm more of an Oracle person myself.  But I think this conversation is going around in circles until we all clarify why partitioning is useful and why multiple tables with the same structure and semantics is an antipattern.  You and Raymond are saying the right things, but it isn't getting through.